# Настроить в webview Android правильную работу кнопки назад

Tags: android, javascript, webview

Здравствуйте!

Сразу скажу - я не программист, я заказчик, поэтому есть что не так скажу - камнями не кидайтесь, пожалуйста.

Я заказал клиент к сайту - webview с выходом только на один сайт, в общем мне его сделали, но возникла одна проблема - по умолчанию в webview системная кнопка назад закрывает приложение, а ссылка на сайте в виде a `href="javascript:history.go(-1)` уходит в цикл, то есть - со страницы 1 пользователь переходит на 2, а потом на 3, а потом нажимает кнопку назад и со страницы 3 возвращается на 2, при нажатии на кнопку назад ещё раз пользователь снова попадает на страницу 3, а не на страницу 1, а потом с 3 опять на 2, с 2 опять на 3 и так вечно. При этом, если написать ссылку вида a `href="javascript:history.go(-10)` - система сделает 10 шагов назад, а потом один вперед и снова цикл.

Решение было найдено примерно такое:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
    mWebView.goBack();
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Я, честно говоря, не знаю, что это и куда вставляется, так как я уже говорил, что я не программист, но думаю Вам будет понятно.

В таком случае системная кнопка назад работает как надо - делает один шаг назад, ссылка вида a `href="javascript:history.go(-X)`" перестает уходить в цикл, но появляется новая проблема, ссылка вида a `href="javascript:history.go(-X)`" делает не X шагов назад, как раньше, а только 1, независимо от значения X. В других webview я наблюдал что можно заставить работать и системную кнопку нормально, и на сайте правильно, но программист, которому я заказал - не знает как это сделать.

Я поискал и нашел возможное решение - вместо `goBack` использовать `goBackOrForward()`, но программист, которому я заказал приложение, понятия не имеет, как это можно использовать, а я и подавно.

В общем, задача в решении которой я прошу помощи - реализовать работу кнопки "назад", как системной так и с помощью скрипта на сайте вида a `href="javascript:history.go(-x)`" в webview на Андроид. Нужно, что бы кнопка назад вида history.go(-x) делала X шагов назад, системная при этом может или делать несколько шагов назад, или по одному шагу назад, или вообще выходить из приложения - не важно. Главное, что бы кнопка history.go(-x) работала и не зацикливалась.

Помогите пожалуйста, знающие люди! Простите, если что коряво объяснил, если что - задавайте вопросы, я постараюсь ответить!  Спасибо!

*update 25.05.2014*

Вот, раскопал код активити:

```
package mobi.infa.smolik;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity
  extends Activity
{
  ProgressBar loadingProgressBar;
  ProgressBar loadingTitle;
  WebView mWebView;

  public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context paramContext)
  {
    ConnectivityManager localConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)paramContext.getSystemService("connectivity");
    return (localConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null) && (localConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()) && (localConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected());
  }

  protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    requestWindowFeature(1);
    setContentView(2130903040);
    final Context localContext = getApplicationContext();
    this.loadingProgressBar = ((ProgressBar)findViewById(2131165185));
    this.mWebView = ((WebView)findViewById(2131165186));
    this.mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    this.mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("infa_android_v0_1");
    this.mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.site.ru");
    this.mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
      public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String paramAnonymousString, GeolocationPermissions.Callback paramAnonymousCallback)
      {
        paramAnonymousCallback.invoke(paramAnonymousString, true, false);
      }

      public void onProgressChanged(WebView paramAnonymousWebView, int paramAnonymousInt)
      {
        super.onProgressChanged(paramAnonymousWebView, paramAnonymousInt);
        MainActivity.this.loadingProgressBar.setProgress(paramAnonymousInt);
        if (paramAnonymousInt == 100)
        {
          MainActivity.this.loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(4);
          return;
        }
        MainActivity.this.loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(0);
      }
    });
    WebViewClient local2 = new WebViewClient()
    {
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView paramAnonymousWebView, String paramAnonymousString)
      {
        if (paramAnonymousString.contains("infa.mobi"))
        {
          if (paramAnonymousString.equalsIgnoreCase(MainActivity.this.mWebView.getUrl()))
          {
            MainActivity.this.mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
          }
          if (MainActivity.checkInternetConnection(localContext))
          {
            MainActivity.this.mWebView.loadUrl(paramAnonymousString);
            return true;
          }
          Toast localToast = Toast.makeText(localContext, "Отсутствует интернет соединение!", 1);
          localToast.setGravity(17, 0, 0);
          localToast.show();
          return true;
        }
        Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
        localIntent.setData(Uri.parse(paramAnonymousString));
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
        return true;
      }
    };
    this.mWebView.setWebViewClient(local2);
  }

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu paramMenu)
  {
    paramMenu.add("На главную");
    paramMenu.add("Поделиться");
    paramMenu.add("О программе");
    paramMenu.add("Выход");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(paramMenu);
  }

  public boolean onBackPressed(int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent)
  {
    if (paramKeyEvent.getAction() == 0) {}
    switch (paramInt)
    {
    default: 
      return super.onBackPressed(paramInt, paramKeyEvent);
    }
    if (this.mWebView.canGoBack()) {
      this.mWebView.goBack();
    }
    for (;;)
    {
      return true;
      finish();
    }
  }

  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem paramMenuItem)
  {
    if (paramMenuItem.getTitle().toString().contains("главную")) {
      this.mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.site.ru/");
    }
    if (paramMenuItem.getTitle().toString().contains("делиться"))
    {
      Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
      localIntent.setType("text/plain");
      localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "http://www.site.ru");
      localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "Классный сайт!");
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "Поделиться"));
    }
    if (paramMenuItem.getTitle().toString().contains("ыход")) {
      finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(paramMenuItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: А почему просто не переопределить метод onBackPressed() у Activity, внутри которого находится webView?

Comment: Я спрошу у программиста, просто сам я веб-программист, и к сожалению ничего не понимаю(( Выглядит конечно глупо, просто мне не хотелось бы терять из-за этого средства, которые я уже оплатил, поэтому я и прибег к такому нетрадиционному способу - задавать вопросы по теме, в которой сам ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Обновил пост. Проблема так и не решена - программист говорит что не знает, что делать. Я расковырял приложение, нашел код активити в файле mainActivity.java.
Может по коду можно понять, в чем проблема?

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Могу помочь, но нужно полностью проект смотреть! 

Answer (score 4):

Прошу прощения, может не до конца понял вопрос.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView view;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    view.loadUrl("http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/history-object.php");
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (view.canGoBack()) {
        view.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Отлично выполняет ваши требования. По нажатию на назад идет до упора по хистори вебвью и затем закрывает активити.  Если вы в загруженной странице кликните на `demo of the history object`, то перейдете на страницу где используется history.go(-1). По клику на `go -1` вернетесь обратно.

Answer (score 0):

У меня сработало вот такое решение

```
 webView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
{
  WebView webView = (WebView) v;

  switch(keyCode)
  {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
      if(webView.canGoBack())
      {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
      }
      break;
  }
}

return false;
}
 });
```

Взял его с сайта https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.webkit.WebView/canGoBack